# Binding value to a complex object, submitting a simple property

Tags: knockout.js, html-select

I have a model like the following:

```js
function Foo() {
    var self = this;    

    self.options = [{id: 1, text: "lorem"}, {id: 2, text: "ipsum"}];
    self.selectedValue = ko.observable(initialValue);

    self.selectedObject = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.fields, function (f) {
            return f.id == self.selectedValue();
        })[0];
    });
}
```

Which is, of course, bound to a `select`:

```html
<select data-bind="options: options, 
                   optionsText: 'text',
                   optionsValue: 'id',
                   value: selectedValue">
```

The `ko.computed` hack is because I have another binding (in a different object, not shown) that needs to access the full object, while the value needs to be a plain Id, so it can be submitted (I'm using a standard `form`, not a custom call)

I'd like to get rid of the hack (which I'm doing in a few more places). Ideally, I would define a single `selected` property in my model, which would have the object, but the `select` value would be correct on submit.

It has to work two ways too: I might have an initial value to select.

Is this doable? Should I research custom bindings? Does it already exist?

I could do it the other way around (i.e. like I'm doing now), but I'd like it to be cleaner. I guess I can just write a `lookup(array, property, value)` helper, but maybe there's a better way.

Comment: I'm scratching my head. Are the option id's of 1 intentional?

Comment: Nope, that was a typing error. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use an extender. For instance, the following one:

```
ko.extenders.plainObject = function(target, options) {
    target.plainValue = function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(options, function (f) {
            return f.id == target();
        })[0];        
    }
    return target;
};
```

You would just have to call selectedValue.plainValue() to get the object, and selectedValue() to get the id, as usual. Please take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C5f98/2/

You can reuse the extender everywhere.

Edit: You can even make it more generic by passing the field to compare as an option (instead of hardcoding "id"). For instance: http://jsfiddle.net/pUudD/